# MVC receiving Value cannot be null or empty

Tags: list, razor, model-view-controller

I have created an ordering system which has a page that allows the end user to place/add to an order and then move to the next page to review the entire order.

I want to be able to have the user move back to the order page from the review order page and see the quantity that was just added/placed...so if I order 2 of widget A, I move to the review page and see that I have an order with 2 A widgets for a particular cost; I then move back to the order page and the quantity of 2 should still be visible to the end user and displayed with Widget A.

I have worked all of this out UNTIL I try to redisplay the Order page and its associated fields.

I get a Value cannot be null or empty error; I realize the meaning of this error and I have stepped through the code and can see that I have data!!  I see nothing that is null nor empty that should not be.

What am I doing wrong?

My code:

```
      menuIndex = 0;
      intMenuTable1 = 3;

      foreach (var menu_item in Model.OrderMenu)
      {
        if (menuIndex < intMenuTable1)
        {
            <tr>
                <td align="center">
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.OrderMenu[menuIndex].Quantity, new { @class = "form-control", @style = "width:50px; height:50px;text-align:center; margin-top:50px; margin-left:10px;"})
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.OrderMenu[menuIndex].ID)
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.OrderMenu[menuIndex].ProductPrice) - **error is here**
                </td>
                <td align="center">
                    <img id="imgProduct" src=@Url.Content(@menu_item.ProductImage) />
                </td>
            </tr>
         }
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

The error was actually BELOW the line that was coming across as an error.

I was not passing all of the model elements that I needed to recreate the view, hence the NULL values.